# overloaded assignment operator - char pointers not copying correctly

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I have a class User that looks like this:

```
class User
{
    private:
        char* p_username;
        int nProcesses; 
        struct time
        {
            int mins;
            int secs;
        } totalTime;        
        int longestPID;     
        char* p_longestPath;    
    public:
        User();
        User(const char[],int,int,int,const char[]);
        ~User();
        User operator=(const User&);
        // Other functions
};
```

And the overloaded assignment operator function is:

```
User User::operator=(const User &u)
{
    if (this != &u)
    {
        delete [] p_username;
        delete [] p_longestPath;
        p_username = new char[strlen(u.p_username)+1];
        strcpy(p_username,u.p_username);
        nProcesses = u.nProcesses;
        totalTime.mins = u.totalTime.mins;
        totalTime.secs = u.totalTime.secs;
        longestPID = u.longestPID;
        p_longestPath = new char[strlen(u.p_longestPath)+1];
        strcpy(p_longestPath,u.p_longestPath);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

A sample main program using the assignment operator:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "\n\nProgram\n\n";

    User u("Username",20,30,112233,"Pathname"),u2;
    u2 = u;
}
```

When I try to use the assignment operator in the line u2 = u, everything is assigned properly except the dynamic char arrays.

Test output from the end of the operator= function shows that at the end of the assignment itself everything has works perfectly (the usernames and pathnames are correct), however test output from the main function directly after the assignment shows that all of a sudden the char arrays have changed. Suddenly the username of u2 is empty, and the first half of the pathname is garbage.

If at the end of the assignment operator function the username and pathname are perfect, how can they be wrong back in the calling function?

This really has me stumped...

Edit: Here are the constructors

```
User::User()
{
    p_username = 0;
    nProcesses = 0;
    totalTime.mins = 0;
    totalTime.secs = 0;
    longestPID = -1;
    p_longestPath = 0;
}


User::User(const char UID[],int minutes,int seconds,int PID,const char path[])
{
    p_username = new char[strlen(UID)+1];
    strcpy(p_username,UID);
    nProcesses = 1; 
    totalTime.mins = minutes;
    totalTime.secs = seconds;
    longestPID = PID;
    p_longestPath = new char[strlen(path)+1];
    strcpy(p_longestPath,path);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `std::vector<char>`s, or `std::string`s, or at least `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`s?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This isn't bad for a first question, but there's a lot of code in there we don't need to see.  In the future, please try to post a *minimal* compilable code sample that demonstrates the problem.  In this case, the only parts that are relevant are the C-style strings.  The rest of the class is just noise, and distracts us from the real problem at hand.

Comment: @Kristo - ok I'll work on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning by value from the assignment function. It is possible that your copy constructor is flawed.

Comment: I don't have a copy constructor. I'm also not calling a copy constructor anywhere so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @BugalugsNash: You _do_ have a copy constructor, and you _are_ calling it (otherwise your code would not compile). The fact that the copy constructor is the implicitly defined default one just proves that it is flawed.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

I changed the function header to:

    User& operator=(const User&)


I.e. the return value is now by reference. Fixed the problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where am I calling the copy constructor?

Comment: @BugalugsNash: The copy constructor is called to initialize the return value of `operator=` (That is - `return *this` copy constructs the return value with `*this`)

Comment: Right. So from my understanding that was only happening when I was returning by value..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this tutorial here:
http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Here is an example from there:

```
  MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass &rhs) {

    // Only do assignment if RHS is a different object from this.
    if (this != &rhs) {
      ... // Deallocate, allocate new space, copy values...
    }

    return *this;
  }
```